# Query with data from subform and sum

Tags: ms-access, sum, subform

I have three tables:

```
Products(ID,Name,Price) / 
Customer(ID, Name, Surname)
Buys(ID, ID_customer, ID_product)
```

I have a form with subform. Subform gets populated with query from Buys table and then connected to Customer(ID) via ID_customer. ID and ID_customer gets hidden on subform.

Then I have two more fields/controls added on subform: Name and aPrice which gets populated via ProductsQuery:

```
SELECT Products.Name, Products.Price
FROM Products
WHERE (((Products.ID)=[Forms]![PregledKupcev-Form]![NAKUPI-Subform]![ID]));
```

//ID in this case is control on subform which holds ID of a product

using:

```
=DLookUp("[Name]";"[ProductsQuery]")
```

and

```
=DLookUp("[Price]";"[ProductsQuery]")
```

So far everything works but it gives me alot of troubles later when i try to sum one control (Price in this case).

Is there any way to do this better?

Then I try to sum up things in aPrice control into PriceSum control on subform's footer:

```
=Sum([Forms]![PregledKupcev-Form]![NAKUPI-subform]![aPrice])
```

and transfer it to form with:

```
=[Forms]![PregledKupcev-Form]![NAKUPI-subform]![PriceSum]
```

but I get error..

How do I sum up values in Price control on subform?

Pictures:
[image: Form]

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that your main form has a text box named `txtInvoiceNo` in which you display the Invoice Number (or whatever field links your parent table to your child table).

Let's also say that your main form has a text box named `txtInvoiceTotal` where you want to display the sum of the [Price] values for each child record.

Set the Control Source of the `txtInvoiceTotal` text box to do a `DSum()` on the child table (which I've called `InvoiceLineItems`):

`=DSum("[Price]","InvoiceLineItems","InvoiceNo=" & [txtInvoiceNo])`

In the `After Update` event of the subform, add a line to `.Requery` the parent form's `txtInvoiceTotal` text box:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
Me.Parent.txtInvoiceTotal.Requery
End Sub
```

See if that does the trick for you.